# What's the best way to search a column that has multiple values separated by commas

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called `Genre` with values like `Action, Crime, Mystery, Comedy`

I need to search the column for Crime, Mystery for example

How can I do that efficiently

eg sudo code  `select * from movie where genre is thriller and romance` or `select * from movie where genre is action and comedy`

To clarify, in the second query i need need movies returned that have action and comedy in their genre field

Comment: You have multiple values in the same field seperated by commas? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: The best adivce is to not store data that you are going to want to filter by in this manner.  You should probably have two additional tables - one the list all available genres and one that relates your movie to the genres that are applicable for it.

Comment: @MikeBrant its too late now this is how the database is and I can't change it now

Comment: @code578841441 It is software.  It should evolve over time. Don't let bad design mistakes continue to inform future designs. Creating a script to migrate your table data to a new schema would be trivial.

Comment: @code578841441 There are plenty of stored procedures to normalize this anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select * from movie
where find_in_set('Crime',genre) > 0
and find_in_set('Romance',genre) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have it correct, but you will probably have to use [wild cards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) in your query. These can be placed before and after the part of string you want.

`Select * FROM movie WHERE genre like '%Crime%' or genre like '%Action%'`

But honestly you should probably organize your data in a different way than this.